# Using javascript, how to add $ sign before any input element on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript, how do I add '$' sign before any input field on an HTML page?

Comment: FYI, if you wrap your in an element like a `label` for example, you can do this with CSS using `label::before` and `content: '$';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all input field on page using `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and then use **[Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)** function inside a loop to insert dollar sign `$` before every one of them :

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for ( var i=0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++){
    var text = document.createTextNode('$');
    inputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(text, inputs[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Because jQuery solutions are useless if jQuery isn't being used. And to suggest loading it for something as trivial as this is bad advice. Also, your only explanation was "Try". At least you added a little more since then.

Comment: Very nice update. +1 Though you should probably use the `.parentNode` of each input instead of `document.body` so that it will work irrespective of the position of the input in the DOM. `inputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(text, inputs[i]);`

Comment: @squint I see you're right. Sorry about that, it was a misconception I had on text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use pure CSS to do so, by using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements and wrapping your input containers in `div`'s

```css
.inputContainer:before, .inputContainer::before {
  content: '$';
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="text">  
</div>
```

Comment: Even thought this is a good solution, remember that the OP specifically said "using javascript".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I know. That's why I said alternatively. Maybe the OP didn't think this was possible with CSS?

Comment: I was thinking that too

Comment: Unfortunately using CSS :before or :after to add the dollar sign is currently inaccessible as many screen readers currently ignore :before and :after CSS generated content.

Comment: @DanielTonon as it should be noted, but the OP didn't specify whether or not they need this to be screen reader compatible. Besides almost all websites make use of pseudo elements http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter

Comment: @Adjit: All sites should be as accessible as possible. Accessibility shouldn't be considered optional. Yes, and I love using psudo elements in all my sites but only for decoration. They shouldn't be used as the primary method for conveying information to the user.